# Set plot legend manually / change order

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

following problem:

I have 5000 two dimensional (x/y) Datapoints which consist of 10 different classes. (Stored in an 5000x2 matrix)
All datapoints are plottet in one figure, each class got his own color/marker style.

The order of the Datapoints is **random!** (So maybe it starts with a point out of class1, maybe class8, ... and maybe there is a class5 followed by another class5 and so on...)

Simplified code snippet:

```
figure(1)
for k=1:5000
...
   if class == 1
      ColorValue = 'r'; MarkValue = '+';
      legendset = [legendset;'class1'];
   elseif class == 2
   ...
   end

   plot( Data(k,1), Data(k,2),'color', ColorValue, 'marker', MarkValue );
   hold on;
end

legend(legendset(1:10));
```

So in 'legendset' I have the legendvalues in the order it gets plottet, but since that is in no order and there occur duplicates the legend is totally messed up.

I want a legend that shows each class once from class1-10, independent of the order it gets plottet.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try dividing up your data points into different classes, and then plot each class with a plot command. Then, each class will automatically get a new color, and `legend` will automatically label each one. For instance, if you have the classes of each data point loaded into a vector called `Classes` (say `Classes = [1 8 5 5 ...]` with your example), you might do something like this:

```
nClasses = 10;

for i = 1:nClasses
    % Extract just the data points with class i:
    DataI = Data(Classes == i, :);

    % Form a string with the class name:
    ClassName = sprintf('Class %d', i);

    % Plot this data. The 'DisplayName' property will appear
    %  in the legend.
    plot(DataI(:,1), DataI(:,2), 'DisplayName', ClassName);
    hold all;
end

legend
```

Comment: I hoped that there is a simple way to set the legend "manually", but it seems there isn't.  So I solved my problem more or less like you suggested. Anyway Thank You!